# Closest Road in a Specific Direction

Tags: android

I am currently working with detecting upcoming roads and alerting the user when the road comes near.

I don't want to detect the closest road unconditionally, since a person could be walking alongside a road but never be actually 'close to a road' as such. Instead, I want to detect the closest road that the person walking is going to intercept, not run parallel with.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include more details like maybe some code you currently have or the libraries you are using to obtain this information?